# Xamarin.Android has the same documentation as official Android documentation in Java? The code si similar?

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android

Can I use this doc https://developer.android.com/reference instead of https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/android/? Only for Xamarin.Android framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Android native document can't replace of xamarin offical document completely,

Here are some differences.

1. Development language.Xamarin android offical document is C#, Android native document is Java or Kotlin.
   When you need to write some code in xamarin Android, And you are jave developer please read blew document.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/java-developers
2. `Xamarin.Essentials` provides developers with cross-platform APIs for their mobile applications. Android native document do not have this part.
3. Data and Cloud Services about Azure part.
4. If you meet some issue when develop xamarin android application, Xamarin android document provide troubleshooting tips.

If you begin to learning xamarin android, please read the xamarin android documents firstly, if you need more details about native android, you can read the android native document.